# How does on get blogdown to produce charts?

Tags: r, knitr, blogdown

I have the following Rmd file

````
---
title: test
author: someone
date: '2017-10-09'
slug: test
categories: [cbla, cblah, cmmm]
tags: [bla, blah, mmm]
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    fig_width: 6
    dev: "svg"
---


```{r cool-plot, fig.width='80%', fig.cap='A cool plot.'}
x <- rnorm(300,0,1)
y <- rnorm(300,0,1)
plot(x,y)
```
````

It produced the following web-page without the plot -- am I doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: To know if you are doing anything wrong, you have to tell us what exactly you did in the first place (i.e. how did you get this page?). Have you read Chapter 1 of the blogdown book? https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/get-started.html

Comment: Many thanks for the response -- I scanned the entire book -- I'll re-read it in greater detail and try to update the post with more details. Thanks.

Comment: @Yihui Xie, when I was calling the new_post() function I didn't specify ext=".Rmd" -- which caused it to produce .md extension-ed files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `blogdown::new_post()` is issued, by default, it creates a Markdown `.md` file and renders text to HTML. In order to make rendering code output or plots, it's necessary to use RMarkdown `.Rmd` file. Change the session settings:

```
options(blogdown.ext = ".Rmd")
```

Or make it permanent by adding the line to `~/Rprofile` file. Open the file within R with `file.edit("~/.Rprofile")`

```
options(blogdown.ext = ".Rmd")
```

See more options [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html).

Answer (score 2):

The answer was very simple.

I was calling the new_post without the required parameter ext=".Rmd"

```
new_post("Notes on the Poisson distribution", date="", ext=".Rmd")
```

So the post files were being generated with the extension ".md"

Newbie error I guess -- it took a while to figure it out.